# open latest file (jpg) in folder

Tags: linux, terminal, imagemagick

My IP camera saves a video (`.mp4` file) and a picture (`.jpg` file) every minute to my Pi, which is set up as an FTP server.

I want to open the latest picture with ImageMagick every 5 minutes.

The filename contains a timestamp, so I don't know how to call the JPEG file in a terminal command. The filename looks like this: `01_20160719210835.jpg`. 
I can find the newest filename in the folder
by doing a `cd` into the folder and running `ls -t *.jpg | head -1`. 
But how can I open an image in ImageMagick based on this?

Also, how can I delete the `.mp4`s hourly?

Comment: I don’t understand your second question. Do you know how to use `cron` (i.e., how to use `crontab`)? Would running `rm *.mp4` hourly via `cron` answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used ImageMagick, so I don’t know what its commands are. 
I presume/hope that you know how to open a file *given its name*. 
(I can imagine that it might be something trivial and straightforward
like `imagemagick filename`
or `open filename`.)

You’re almost there: you should be able to do what you want with

```
command "$(ls -t *.jpg | head -1)"
```

Notes:

- The quotes are an important part of the answer.
- This will fail if you have filename(s) with newline(s) in them.
- This can fail if you have a directory with a name that ends with `.jpg`.

Answer (score 1):

this is my script to add my logo to the latest image and remove all video files,
i run it via cron every 5 minutes

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/dietpi_userdata/webcam/dump
composite -geometry +30+10 /mnt/dietpi_userdata/webcam/logo.png "$(ls -t *.jpg | head -1)" /mnt/dietpi_userdata/webcam/webcam.jpg

convert /mnt/dietpi_userdata/webcam/webcam.jpg -gravity North -pointsize 40 -annotate +30+10 'my homepage' /mnt/dietpi_userdata/webcam/webcam.jpg

rm /mnt/dietpi_userdata/webcam/dump/*.mp4
```

thx for the help

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with ImageMagick? If you just want to display the image and sort by the timestamp in the filename, you can do this:

```
display "$(ls *.jpg | sort -k1.4 | tail -1)"
```

The parameter `-k1.4` makes it to be sorted by the fourth character (ignore `01_` in the beginning).

Comment: Note that ls can already sort on time (e.g. ls -lart).

Comment: Yes, the other answers use `ls` to sort. I just wanted to show another way, which uses the file name.